# Page reloading data every time it's displayed

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-bloc

## Description

GitHub project: [SanwarJW/multi_bloc_provider](https://github.com/SanwarJW/multi_bloc_provider)

I'm facing an issue with state management and navigation in my Flutter application. I have two pages (`HomePage` and `ImageListPage`) where I'm using a bloc. I pass the bloc instance from the HomePage to the ImageListPage. However, every time I navigate to the ImageListPage, the bloc instance seems to reload, causing unexpected behavior.

#### HomePageState

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final imageListBloc = BlocProvider.of<ImageListBloc>(context);

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Home')),
        body: Center(
          child: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => ImageList(
                            imageListBloc: imageListBloc,
                          )));
            },
            child: const Text('Go to Image List'),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

#### ImageList

```
class ImageList extends StatefulWidget {
  final ImageListBloc imageListBloc;
  const ImageList({super.key, required this.imageListBloc});

  @override
  State<ImageList> createState() => _ImageListState();
}

class _ImageListState extends State<ImageList> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    widget.imageListBloc.loadImages();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Image List')),
      body: Center(
        child: StreamBuilder<List<String>>(
          stream: widget.imageListBloc.imageListStream,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
            }
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
            }
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Text(snapshot.data![index]);
                },
              );
            } else {
              // Handle the case when data is not available
              return const Text('No data available');
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The Flutter Bloc code below defines an `ImageListBloc` responsible for managing image list data. It initializes with an initial state and provides a stream of image lists. The `loadImages` method fetches data from `DataList` and emits it to the stream.

#### ImageListBloc

```
DataList dataList = DataList();

class ImageListBloc extends Bloc<ImageListEvent, ImageListState> {
  ImageListBloc() : super(ImageListInitial()) {}

  final _imageListController = StreamController<List<String>>.broadcast();
  Stream<List<String>> get imageListStream => _imageListController.stream;

  loadImages() async {
    if (!_imageListController.hasListener) {
      var dList = await dataList.gitListData();
      _imageListController.sink.add(dList);
    }
  }
}
```

## What I've Tried

- Passing the bloc instance through constructors
- Investigating navigation routes for any potential issues
- Checking if the bloc instance is being properly persisted across navigations

## Expected Outcome

I expect the bloc instance to be maintained without reloading when navigating between `HomePage` and `ImageListPage`, ensuring consistent behavior and state management.

***Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand the purpose of passing the `ImageListBloc` instance into the `ImageList` widget.

I see you already added it in main() `BlocProvider<ImageListBloc>(create: (context) => ImageListBloc())`, then just call `context.read<ImageListBloc>(); to get the BLoc instance within the widget tree`.

And there is no use of the Bloc at all in your widget, your usage of the Bloc is just like a random class that contains the StreamController.

The `ImageList` reloads every time you navigate to it because the `loadImages()` function is called in the `initState()` method before the `build` method runs. As a result, there is no listener for the `StreamController`, and without any listeners, the data will be fetched.

When you navigate back, the `ImageList` widget is disposed and its listener is removed from the stream.

**How to fix**

My suggestion is to use the BLoc correctly, add some more state to the `ImageListState`

```
part of 'image_list_bloc.dart';

@immutable
sealed class ImageListState {}

final class ImageListInitial extends ImageListState {}
final class ImageListLoading extends ImageListState {}

final class ImageListLoaded extends ImageListState {
  final List<String> listData;
  ImageListLoaded ({required this.listData});
}

final class ImageListError extends ImageListState {}
```

`ImageListBloc` (I'm using Cubit here for simple example)

```
class ImageListBloc extends Cubit<ImageListState> {
  ImageListBloc() : super(ImageListInitial()) {}

  loadImages() async {
    emit(ImageListLoading());
    var dList = await dataList.gitListData();
    emit(ImageListLoaded(listData: dList));
  }
}
```

`main()`

```
BlocProvider<ImageListBloc>(create: (context) => ImageListBloc()..loadImages())
```

`ImageList`

```
class ImageList extends StatefulWidget {
  const ImageList({super.key});

  @override
  State<ImageList> createState() => _ImageListState();
}

class _ImageListState extends State<ImageList> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Image List')),
      body: BlocBuilder<ImageListBloc, ImageListState>(
        buildWhen: (old, current) {
          return current is ImageListLoading || current is ImageListLoaded || current is ImageListError;
        },
        builder: (context, state) {
          if(state is ImageListLoading) {
            return const CircularProgressIndicator();
          }

          if(state is ImageListError) {
            return Text('Error');
          }

          if(state is ImageListLoaded) {
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: (state).listData.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Text((state).listData[index]);
              },
            );
          }

          return const Text('No data available');
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Finally, correct the navigation call

```
 Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ImageList())
 );
```

Comment: Thank you for providing the initial code! It was indeed quite helpful. I found that the code mostly met my requirements, but I encountered an issue where the ImageListBloc wasn't visible on the ImageList page. To resolve this, I opted to use BlocProvider.value to ensure that the ImageListBloc instance is accessible throughout the widget tree. This adjustment helped resolve the visibility issue, and now everything works as expected. Once again, thank you for your help

Comment: It's great to hear that it was helpful! Happy coding!